# avconv: Overylaying multiple videos with offset

Tags: avconv

I am trying to overlay multiple videos in a split screen, with different offset (Audio, video both offset), initially I tried offsetting & overlaying like following

```
avconv -i 1.webm -itsoffset 2 -s 640x480 -vf "movie=1.webm, scale=320:480 [vid2]; [vid2] overlay=0:0 [basis1]; [basis1][1] overlay=320:0" splitScreenOut.mp4
```

& overlayed videos being offset by:

```
movie=overlay.avi:seek_point=1.4
```

But this approach didn't worked on my end, the `-itsoffset` offsets entire video output & `seek_point` wasn't recognized by my `avconv` build.

Then I tried offsetting each video individually.

```
avconv -itsoffset 4 -i 1.webm -c copy tmp1.webm
```

& simply overlaying

```
avconv -i tmp1.webm -s 640x480 -vf "[in] scale=640/3:480, pad=3.01*iw:ih [video0]; movie=tmp2.webm, scale=640/3:480 [video1];[video0][video1] overlay=(640)/3:0 [VidO1]; movie=tmp3.webm, scale=640/3:480 [video2];[VidO1][video2] overlay=(640/3)*2:0 [out]" -b:v 768k Output.webm<
```

The problem is all video start in split screen, from offset of first video as if individually offsetting didn't worked.